# javascript not working in php programme

Tags: javascript

I have a script written in JavaScript and I need to convert this validation in php. SO my current JavaScript validation is not working in php. Any idea. Here is the code.

```
function save_product()

    var productcombo = document.getElementById('productcombo').object;    
    var batchcombo = document.getElementById('batchcombo').object;    

    if(productcombo.GetTextValue()=="" )
    {
        alert("Select Product Name");
        productcombo.SetFocus();
    }  
    else if(batchcombo.GetTextValue()=="" )
    {
        alert("Select Product Batch No");
        batchcombo.SetFocus();
    }  
    else if(document.getElementById("qty").value=="" )
    {
        alert("Enter inward quantity");
        document.getElementById("qty").focus();
    }  
    else if(document.getElementById("qty").value!="" && (parseInt(document.getElementById("qty").value)>parseInt(document.getElementById("productqty").value)))
    {
        var pq=document.getElementById("productqty").value;
        alert("Enter quantity less than "+pq+"");
        document.getElementById("qty").focus();
    }  
    else
    { 
        var productgrid = nitobi.getGrid('productgrid');
        productgrid.insertRow();

        productgrid.setActiveRow(0,0);

        var rowno=productgrid.getSelectedRow();
        productgrid.getCellObject(0,2).setValue(document.getElementById("productsrno").value);
        productgrid.getCellObject(0,3).setValue(productcombo.GetTextValue());            
        productgrid.getCellObject(0,4).setValue(productcombo.GetSelectedRowValues()[6]);
        productgrid.getCellObject(0,5).setValue(batchcombo.GetTextValue());            
        productgrid.getCellObject(0,6).setValue(document.getElementById("qty").value);            
        productgrid.getCellObject(0,7).setValue(document.getElementById("boxes").value);            
        productgrid.getCellObject(0,8).setValue(document.getElementById("rate").value);            
        productgrid.getCellObject(0,9).setValue(document.getElementById("price").value);            
        get_resetproduct();
        productcombo.SetFocus();
        calTotal();
        calVat();
        document.getElementById("save1").disabled=false;
        document.getElementById("reset1").disabled=false;
        document.getElementById("delete1").disabled=true;
        check_user()
    }
}
```

When I click on submit button a new blank data gets saved in DB which is wrong. I need validation to work.

Comment: forgot { after func declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program will always be ( probably ) a bit in javascript and a bit in php.
If you don't want use javascript at all, but i cannot see any reason for that, you should just submit the form how it is.
Given your action method "get" or "post" you will retrive de data in php script.

The problem here is very complex to explain.

The point is that php is running on your server and will never serFocus() or give you alerts().

You should do a form validation in javascript improving your function.
If you are in some situation that the form validation has a secret alghoritm and you want to run it in php, just send all the data and make this function that will return true or false or will return the input that is failing the control. A script in your page will wait for the response ( jquery or any other ) and will give the user the correct messages.
Setting focus, giving alerts, higlighting something.

You cannot translate javascript to PHP in most cases it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks Andrea for the explanation. I'l probably use Jquery or HTML 5 validation in this case.

Comment: Remind any javascript function is fine. It has to return something evaluable to true or false and you have to have it on the form onsubmit attribute. onsubmit="return my_validation()". Html5 and jquery are cool but not requirements

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [jQuery Form Validator](http://formvalidator.net/). It's easy to use and very better that write your own form validation.

Example:

```
<form action="/registration" method="POST">
    <p>
        Name (4 characters minimum):
        <input name="user" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min4">
    </p>
    <p>
        Year (yyyy-mm-dd):
        <input name="birth" data-validation="date" data-validation-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
    </p>
    <p>
        Website:
        <input name="website" data-validation="url">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit">
    </p>
</form>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.1.47/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.validate();
</script>
```

and many features:

```
<!-- An answer has to be given -->
<input data-validation="required" type="text">

<!-- Max 100 characters -->
<input data-validation="length" data-validation-length="max100" type="text">

<!-- Minimum 20 characters -->
<input data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min20" type="text">

<!-- No less than 50 characters and no more than 200 characters -->
<input data-validation="length" data-validation-length="50-200" type="text">

<!-- Any numerical value -->
<input data-validation="number" type="text">

<!-- Only allowing float values -->
<input data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="float" type="text">

<!-- Allowing float values and negative values -->
<input data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="float,negative" type="text">

<!-- Validate float number with comma separated decimals -->
<input data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="float" 
         data-validation-decimal-separator="," type="text">

<!-- Only allowing numbers from 1 to 100 -->
<input data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="range[1;100]" type="text">

<!-- Only allowing numbers from -50 to 30 -->
<input data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="range[-50;30],negative" type="text">

<!-- Only allowing numbers from 0.05 to 0.5 -->
<input data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="range[0.05;0.5],float" type="text">
```

[More](http://formvalidator.net/)